# Is it possible to write universal component? (react/typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to write universal component? which receives some object with similar data (for example: id, title, text, date) and renders it. But all objects have different keynames. Three objects for example, all of them have id, title, text, and date:

```
obj1 {id: 1, textVar: 'textString1', titleVar: 'titleString1', date1: '2000-10-10'}

obj2 {id: 2, title2: 'titleString2', someDate: '2001-11-11', otherTextVar: 'textString2'}

obj3 {id: 3, otherText3: 'textString3', otherDate: '2000-10-10', newsTitle: 'titleString3'}
```

Is it possible to write universal component, which can work with any of objects?

```
interface UCompProps {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    text: string,
    date: string,
  }, 
}

const UComponent: React.FC<UCompProps> = (props) => {
  const { id, title, text, date } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <div>{id}</div>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <div>{date}</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default UCompProps
```

Have no idea how to do it. Any advice how to do it?

Comment: Yes, you could use Object.entries on props, but doesn't feel right to me..  The code above you may as well have just sent an array or object in 1 prop.

Comment: If the order of id, title, text, date are the same then you could easily use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: No its havent the same order. all problem is I can't know what is what. Title and text is strings, and it can have any keynames :(

Comment: Any chance you can control how the input ins generated ?

Comment: The backend is written by other people, and there is some very similar data. I need to make a component that outputs a preview for that data. (for ex: news list, articles list, sales list, and other.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know structures of all objects, then you can map array of that objects.

```
// in parent:
return (
  <div>
    {arrayOfobjects1
      .map(obj1=>({
        id:obj1.id, title:obj1.titleVar , text:obj1.textVar, date: obj1.date1
      }))
      .map(props=><Ucomponent key={props.id} {...props} />)
    }
  </div>
)
```

And also you can define that mapping functions for each types of objects:

```
// in parent:

const mapper1 = object1 => ({id:obj1.id, title:obj1.titleVar, text:obj1.textVar, date: obj1.date1});

return (
  <div>
    {arrayOfobjects1
      .map(mapper1)
      .map(props=><Ucomponent key={props.id} {...props} />)
    }
  </div>
)
```

Or you can render them all together after mapping of each array

```
const arrayToRender = [...arr1.map(mapper1), ...arr2.map(mapper2), ...arr3.map(mapper3)];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order of id, title, text, date are the same then you could easily use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
const UComponent = (props) => {
  const { id, title, text, date } = props;
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>ID: {id}</div>
      <div>TITLE: {title}</div>
      <div>TEXT: {text}</div>
      <div>DATE: {date}</div>
      <br/>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;

  const components = data.map((obj) => {
    const [id, title, text, date] = Object.values(obj);
    return <UComponent id={id} title={title} text={text} date={date} />;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {components}
    </div>
  )
}

const objs = [
  {id: 1, titleVar: 'titleString1', date1: '2000-10-10', textVar: 'textString1'},
  {id: 2, title2: 'titleString2', someDate: '2001-11-11', otherTextVar: 'textString2'},
  {id: 3, newsTitle: 'titleString3', otherDate: '2000-10-10', otherText3: 'textString3'},
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={objs} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```